# How to set default sound on Firebase Console for http v1 push messages

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This question is specific of Firebase Console notifications for **version http v1** on Android. iOS works.

Please, do not set it as duplicate unless there's a question regarding that especific version!

I cannot find a way to send a proper push notification with sound set as default. I have looked extensevely at [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) but they lack any functional example!!!

Do you know a functional example of a valid json format for android push notification, through **Firebase Console, version http v1**, with the key "sound" set as default?

This format works, notification is received on all devices, some sound, and some doesn't. It is not a device issue. They are enabled on device settings.

```
const requestBody1 = {
        message: {
            token: deviceToken,
            sound: "default",
            notification: {
                body: theMsg,
                title: theTitle
            },
            apns: {
                "payload": {
                    "aps": {
                        "sound": "default"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

};
```

I have tested lots of different json (never mind the quotes) formats to get sound:"default". They all return some error:

I.E

```
const requestBody = {
    "message":{
        "android": {
            "collapse_key": "a collapse key",
            "priority": "normal",
            "ttl": "10s",
            "restricted_package_name": "com.test.app",
            "data": {
                "dummydata" : "dummydata",
            },
            "notification": {
                "title": "one title",
                "body": "one message",
                "sound": "default"
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was get JSON data like below :

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        Session session=new Session(this);
        try {
            JSONObject data=new JSONObject(message.getData().get("data"));
            System.out.println("------------------- Notification Received : " + data.toString());
            if(!session.getUserId().equals(null)) {
                if(!session.getUserId().equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("---------------------- USERID : " + session.getUserId());
                    sendMyNotification(data.get("body").toString(), data.get("title").toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("----------------Error in onMessageReceived : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("----------------Error in onMessageReceived : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

And my Json data which i send is like below :

```
{
 "to" : "User Token" : {

    "data" :{
         "body" : "Hello, How are you?",
         "title": "Notification From API"
    }
 }
}
```

you can send default sound for notification like this, but if you have sound uri than you can directly set by setting the property of setSound() :

and you can convert string to uri like this : `Uri myUri = Uri.parse("Your String data")`

```
Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel("my_notification","n_channel",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("description");
            notificationChannel.setName("Channel Name");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.listlogo)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tlogo))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setChannelId("my_notification")
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#3F5996"));
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```